# insert seperate date and time into one timestamp field

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to insert a separate date field, and a separate time field from a php form, and insert it into my database, in on field. the inserted value must be as a unix timestamp. The date field uses a jquery datepicker, and the time field uses the timepicker plugin. Here is the markup for the form handler, once the values have been submitted:

```
$json = array();

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

$date_from = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['date_from']);
$time_from = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['time_from']);


if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})$/", $date_from)) {
$json['error']['date_from'] = 'Start Date is not valid!';
}

if (!preg_match("/^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $time_from)) {
$json['error']['time_from'] = 'Start Time is not valid!';
}



if (isset($json['error']) and !empty($json['error'])){

$json['status'] = 'error';
$json['message'] = 'Please check your error(s)!';

}else{

$json['status'] = 'success';
$json['message'] = 'Time Data has been successfully updated!';

}

}

echo json_encode($json);
```

How do I insert the `date_from` and `time_from` fields into one database field called `start_time` as a timestamp.
P.S  I know I need to use the `strtotime` function

Answer (score 0):

try just doing `strtotime($date_from." ".$time_from)`;